# Styling Om components

Tags: css, clojurescript, om

The way to style and Om component is based on how React handles styling.
It would be a horrible mess to duplicate common CSS rules all over the application so is there a way to define the styles in a function or similar?

```
(defn my-css [] {:border "1px solid #000"})

(defn my-component [state]
  (dom/div #js {:className "the-class-name"
                :style #js (my-css)}))
```

I've tried using `defn` and `def` but I can't find a way to avoid

`Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: JavaScript literal must use map or vector notation`

Comment: I think you don't need second #js after :style

Comment: FWIW, make sure you understand #js. It's a reader macro and happens while the clojurescript compiler reads in the file/form. It says what it expects. Not the namespace is from a clojure(!) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
(defn create-style [row]
  {:background-color (utils/get-background-color (:task_status row)) :color (utils/get-color (:task_status row))})
```

But I am using it with "om-bootstrap".

I have the #js sometimes before the :style map and sometimes after.  I think it depends on what they library is expecting.

Comment: I just figured out that it worked flawlessly with a ```(def my-css #js {:color "#ff0")```. All it took was to prefix the map with ```#js```